# Get the parent record with highest level value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck on one SQL Query, can any one help me? Following is my table [LEVEL]

With columns

```
Name Varchar(50), ObjectId Int, ParentId Int, LevelId int
```

Following are the records:

```
INSERT INTO [LEVEL] (Name,ObjectId,ParentId,LevelId) VALUES('Test',1,NULL,10);
INSERT INTO [LEVEL] (Name,ObjectId,ParentId,LevelId) VALUES('3rdItem',2,1,50);
INSERT INTO [LEVEL] (Name,ObjectId,ParentId,LevelId) VALUES('1stItem',3,2,30);
INSERT INTO [LEVEL] (Name,ObjectId,ParentId,LevelId) VALUES('test',4,3,40);
INSERT INTO [LEVEL] (Name,ObjectId,ParentId,LevelId) VALUES('2ndItem',5,3,40);
INSERT INTO [LEVEL] (Name,ObjectId,ParentId,LevelId) VALUES('test tom',6,3,40);
INSERT INTO [LEVEL] (Name,ObjectId,ParentId,LevelId) VALUES('waterweg23',7,3,40);
INSERT INTO [LEVEL] (Name,ObjectId,ParentId,LevelId) VALUES('test',4,2,10);
```

I need to get the records with parents having max Level Id.

Here record "test" has 2 parents i.e. (3 & 2) it should show for 'test' with parent 2 only, as Object 2 has highest level id than 3. 
It should return only one record ParentId = 2 for 'test'.

So I want to get all the records with Parent having max levelId

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: actually this one looks suspiciosly similar to that one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235856/recursive-sql-relation-query, only tags are different. I don't get it - why do you do that? Are you sure you're working in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if you are looking for this

```
 SELECT Name, ObjectId, ParentId, MAX(LevelId) AS LevelId FROM LEVEL GROUP BY Name;
```

You can try the query in the DEMO LINK provided by @Prix in his answer. I tried there too ;)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your query does not meet the requirements as it does not return all records as he asked.

Comment: @Prix: He said he wants all records with max levelid. 
"So I want to get all the records with Parent having max levelId". I might be wrong in understanding the question, but the above line within quotes made me answer that.

Comment: Well it doesn't list 1stItem and 3rdItem so its not all records. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c1fe4/14 From what I understood he wants all records with their particular parentid. But then again I am having a hard time myself understanding what he is saying so who knows maybe that is what he wants.

Comment: Yes. Now I see the problem. Thanks @Prix. I will change my answer

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give the required result.

```
select l.objectid, l.parentid 
from level l 
inner join ( 
    select objectid, max ( levelid ) as maxlevel from level 
) as m on l.objectid = m.objectid
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
        select lv.LevelId
          from [LEVEL] lv
    cross join ( select max(p.ParentId) pid from [LEVEL] p ) mp
         where lv.ParentId = mp.pid
             ;
```